# System hangs after pip install in docker build

Tags: python, docker, pip, dockerfile, docker-build

I am running the following Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.6.9
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app

# install dependencies
RUN pip3 install tensorflow==1.15
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

# define the port number
EXPOSE 5000

# run
CMD ["python3", "./index.py"]
```

I am trying to build an image of an ML model deployed on a Flask application. When I run the command my system hangs.

```
sudo docker build -t lhp .
```

I have to restart the system to rerun docker. The build execution stops at `RUN pip3 install tensorflow==1.15`. I have tried this multiple times using pip and pip3 but the error persists. I have also tried replacing tensorflow with other python packages. The problem seems to be with pip and not with the particular python package. Please help me solve this. Following is a copy of my terminal.

```
aishwarya@aishwarya-ThinkPad-W540:/media/aishwarya/2E068D88068D522F/lhp$ sudo docker build -t lhpoc8 .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  452.5MB
Step 1/7 : FROM python:3.6.9
 ---> 5bf410ee7bb2
Step 2/7 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Running in fefe94814764
Removing intermediate container fefe94814764
 ---> e261c29f7c96
Step 3/7 : COPY . /app
 ---> babae5a3fee8
Step 4/7 : RUN pip3 install tensorflow==1.15
 ---> Running in 7e4d9d7e5353
```

That's it. This is where it stops.

**Update**

Here is the image history

```
aishwarya@aishwarya-ThinkPad-W540:/media/aishwarya/2E068D88068D522F/lhp$ sudo docker image history 1c7f12b2e283
IMAGE               CREATED             CREATED BY                                      SIZE                COMMENT
1c7f12b2e283        23 minutes ago      /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY dir:235abf6dd10dddd25…   452MB               
88bcbf8e9815        23 minutes ago      /bin/sh -c #(nop) WORKDIR /app                  0B                  
5bf410ee7bb2        4 months ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["python3"]              0B                  
<missing>           4 months ago        /bin/sh -c set -ex;   wget -O get-pip.py "$P…   6.25MB              
<missing>           4 months ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV PYTHON_GET_PIP_SHA256…   0B                  
<missing>           4 months ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV PYTHON_GET_PIP_URL=ht…   0B                  
<missing>           4 months ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV PYTHON_PIP_VERSION=19…   0B                  
<missing>           4 months ago        /bin/sh -c cd /usr/local/bin  && ln -s idle3…   32B                 
<missing>           4 months ago        /bin/sh -c set -ex   && wget -O python.tar.x…   86.2MB              
<missing>           4 months ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV PYTHON_VERSION=3.6.9     0B                  
<missing>           4 months ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV GPG_KEY=0D96DF4D4110E…   0B                  
<missing>           4 months ago        /bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install…   17.1MB              
<missing>           4 months ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV LANG=C.UTF-8             0B                  
<missing>           4 months ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV PATH=/usr/local/bin:/…   0B                  
<missing>           4 months ago        /bin/sh -c set -ex;  apt-get update;  apt-ge…   510MB               
<missing>           4 months ago        /bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install…   145MB               
<missing>           4 months ago        /bin/sh -c set -ex;  if ! command -v gpg > /…   17.5MB              
<missing>           4 months ago        /bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install…   16.5MB              
<missing>           4 months ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["bash"]                 0B                  
<missing>           4 months ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:9b7d9295bf7e8307b…   114MB
```

Comment: are you sure it doesnt hang on the next line: `RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt`? This seems more plausible

Comment: Nope. I swapped the 2 `RUN pip3` commands and the error always comes on whichever comes first.

Comment: Then it seems the problem is in the call to `pip3` command. Is it accessible and present? For example on my machine where `perl` is also installed `pip` refers to a `perl` script and I need to use full path to access `python`'s `pip`. Something similar might be the case here

Comment: How do I check if it is accessible or present? Doesn't pip3 come along with the parent python3.6.9 image?

Comment: Sometimes it needs an additional setup  https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/

Comment: This time the system got stuck at `RUN curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py` after the `COPY` command

Comment: Ok does the docker machine have internet access at all?

Comment: maybe some ports need to be opened, not sure, maybe it is network acces issue

Comment: It was able to download the base python3.6.9 image. Internet is most likely not the issue.

Comment: maybe it needs additional permission tio access other urls than the docker image repository, just guessing, not sure

Comment: do you have some firewall or sth blocking network access when it comes from the docker machine?

Comment: No such thing is active

Answer (score 1):

install pip first (in this order in your dockerfile)

`RUN pip install -U pip`

then run pip install (ex. for python3)

`RUN python3 -m pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt`

Comment: Now my system hangs at `RUN pip install -U pip` XD

Comment: @AishwaryaHarpale Not sure if still need help but make sure you don't have VPN on when using docker. You won't have internet access in the Docker image, which causes your system to freeze as it keeps attempting to update.

Comment: @RakshitKothari The problem was caused because I had exported my /var/lib/docker to an external drive using symlinks due to shortage of space in my root directory. I expanded my storage space and downloaded docker again. Everything is fine now.

Answer (score 1):

So basically nothing worked. I was facing the error due to some symlinks because I had shifted my Docker storage to another disk. I uninstalled Docker and then eventually, Ubuntu. Increased my Ubuntu partition size till it was big enough to store docker images. Reinstalled Ubuntu, Docker. Now I live in peace with happy and successful docker builds.